# How can I iterate objects in component of Angular 5

Tags: angular, typescript

I have object having string as keys and values. I want to trim all values of object in one go without need to check every index manually.

So, I have to iterate over object and will trim the value and the update value in object.

Can you share a way to iterate any object in Angulario 5.

```
let obj = {
  "name" => "    keshav     ",
  "prof" => "    Engineer   "
}
```

And I would like to this to convert into

```
let obj = {
  "name" => "keshav",
  "prof" => "Engineer"
}
```

Comment: This question is not Anguar(io5) specific. You must also show your attempts to resolve

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Trim white spaces in both Object key and value recursively](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33510625/trim-white-spaces-in-both-object-key-and-value-recursively)

Answer (score 4):

You can use [`Object.entries`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/entries):

```
Object.entries(obj).forEach(([key, value]) => obj[key] = value.trim());
```

This way you maintain the reference of the object

Answer (score 1):

you have to do like this, get all the object properties and then just trim it

```
 const properties = Object.keys(obj );
 properties.forEach(prop=>{
   obj[prop]= obj[prop].trim();  
 });
```

Answer (score 0):

you can us simple `for` as well :

```
for(index in obj) { 
   obj[index] = obj[index].trim();
}
```